# Couchbase doesn't use index with filter when execute parametized N1QL query

Tags: couchbase, sql++, nosql

I had created global secondary index with `where` condition in my Couchbase cluster:

```
CREATE INDEX commentAuthorSecondaryIndex ON Bucket(author) WHERE (_class = "com.company.Comment") USING GSI;
```

then I tried execute two similar queries via N1QL (REST API):

```
curl --header "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8093/query/service -d '
{
  "$class" : "com.company.Comment",
  "statement" : "select count(*) from Bucket WHERE _class = $class and author = $author",
  "$author" : "author455",
  "scan_consistency" : "statement_plus"
}'
```

and :

```
curl --header "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8093/query/service -d '
{  
   "statement" : "select count(*) from Bucket WHERE _class = \"com.company.Comment\" and author = $author",
   "$author" : "author455",
   "scan_consistency" : "statement_plus"
}
```

First query was executed fast 4 seconds while second took only 20 miliseconds.
When I used `explain` keyword I realized that in first query Couchbase doesn't use index.

I suppose that Couchbase firstly create query execution plan and only then evaluate query with parameters. 
So when query plan is created Couchbase doesn't know that index `commentAuthorSecondaryIndex` can be used.

Is any way to fix this?

Comment: Two options--remove the filter from the index, or do not make _class a parameter in the your query. See https://forums.couchbase.com/t/whats-the-best-approach-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-n1ql/11636/8

Comment: Thank you. It's clear now. Are there any plans to fix this in the future?

Comment: Yes, there are plans :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options--remove the filter from the index, or do not make _class a parameter in the your query. See https://forums.couchbase.com/t/whats-the-best-approach-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-n1ql/11636/8